# Trying to find a way to have my viewmodel in compose preview

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, preview

I'm still pretty new to jetpack compose and I have been trying to setup previews to make development easier, but I can't find a way to use ViewModelProvider or get an Application within the preview context.

My TimeViewModel requires an Application to be passed in as a parameter...

```
class TimeViewModel(appObj: Application): AndroidViewModel(appObj) {...
```

Then in my MainActivity I am creating it like this...

```
val timeViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[TimeViewModel::class.java]
```

and that gets passed to any composables that may need it. One in particular is my ProgressView.

I would like to be able to preview my ProgressView, but I can't because it needs that timeViewModel passed to it as the argument.

In my MainActivity it's simple...

```
ProgressView(timeViewModel)
```

But in the @Preview I can't instantiate the TimeViewModel

I have tried doing this...

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewProgress() {
  val timeViewModel = TimeViewModel(LocalContext.current as Application)
  ProgressView(model = timeViewModel)
}
```

but I keep getting a Render problem, clicking on it shows me...

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext cannot be cast to class android.app.Application

I can't use the same method of `ViewModelProvider(this)[TimeViewModel::class.java]` because `this` doesn't exist in the preview context. I also tried using the same `LocalContext.current as Application` but that doesn't work either.

I have tried googling and can't find anything to help me out. Is there a way to use a ViewModelProvider in a @Preview?

I should also mention the TimeViewModel is there for a Room database. The android wear-os-samples git hub, and I believe the code-lab, shows that the view model gets passed the Application in order to create the repo inside of it.

Comment: "My TimeViewModel requires an Application to be passed in as a parameter..." - that's the root of your problem. A `ViewModel` is intended to represent the UI state of a given screen. It should have no need for a reference to the entire Application object, or any Context ideally. Figure out what you need from the Application and provide those objects instead. Then you can pass fakes / stubs in your preview.

Comment: I had followed an example on androids wear-os-samples git repo. In the sample and I believe in a code along tutorial they show the view model getting passed the Application object, it's there to instantiate the repo inside the view model

Comment: Samples and tutorials are often focused on doing one thing, architecture be damned. You should not "instantiate the repo inside the view model", since it locks the VM to that one implemetnation and makes testing harder. You should pass the ViewModel the repo via constructor or dependency injection. Review the architecture guidelines, including [this fun page](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/recommendations#viewmodel) that states: "Do not use AndroidViewModel." Welcome to Android development, where Google provides classes that they advise you don't use. Enjoy your stay.

Comment: ROFL. Thank you sir, I'm sure I'll enjoy it all and be tearing my hair out in no time.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't good to have any context of your UI on your view model, because the view model should only handle the state.

However, if you want to keep the code that way, you can use the MVI design pattern.

Using MVI, the UI will only send events (actions) to the view model, and the view model will be responsible to perform the task, calling any methods as necessary. The UI will only receive the state from view model and changing with it. That way, is easy uncouple view model from the screen. You must have a composable with your content, that receive only state model and a callback send your events (actions) to be possible to preview this Content composable. Now is easy to mock this values.

That is an example how to use MVI pattern with Jetpack Compose.

***TimeViewState.kt***

```
data class TimeViewState(
   val name: String = "",
   val error: Throwable? = null
)
```

***TimeViewEvent.kt***

```
sealed class TimeViewEvent {
    object Set {
        data class Name(val value: String): TimeViewEvent()
        data class Error(val value: Throwable?): TimeViewEvent()
    }
}
```

***TimeViewModel.kt***

```
class TimeViewModel(appObj: Application): AndroidViewModel(appObj) {
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(TimeViewState())
    val state = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    fun dispatchEvent(event: TimeViewEvent) {
        when (event) {
            is TimeViewEvent.Set.Name -> setName(event.value)
            is TimeViewEvent.Set.Error -> setError(event.value)
        }
    }

    private fun setName(value: String) {
        _state.update { it.copy(name = value) }
    }

    private fun setError(value: Throwable?) {
        _state.update { it.copy(error = value) }
    }
}
```

***ProgressView.kt***

```
@Composable
fun ProgressView(viewModel: TimeViewModel) {
    val state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()

    Content(
        state = state,
        event = viewModel::dispatchEvent
    )
}

@Composable
private fun Content(
    state: TimeViewState,
    event: (TimeViewAction) -> Unit
) {
   // your ui here
}

@Preview
@Composable
private fun ContentPreview() {
    Content(TimeViewState()) {}
}
```

Comment: I updated my original post. The TimeViewModel is passed the Application so it can create the TimeRepo inside of it. Since this is for a Room database. I followed the Android wear-os-samples on github and a code lab when I made it.

Comment: You can use the view model scope for this, but when you execute the app will crash because Room cannot run on main thread. In this point you have 2 options:

1 - use 'allowMainThreadQueries()' before on database creation
    'Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDatabase::class.java, "MyDatabase").allowMainThreadQueries().build()'

2 - You can add the 'viewModelScope + Dispatcher.IO' from coroutines lib. That way you database will run on back thread.

Comment: The context for create a database instance do not need necessarily be the application context, so you can use the view model scope.

Comment: You can pass literally this: viewModelScope + Dispatcher.IO

Comment: Just remember to import the plus operator (+).